# GROUP BY to array

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

So I have a database with multiple sku and prices. There are about 10 prices per sku. What i'm trying to do is get an average and median from the script below.

```
function calculate_median($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr); //total numbers in array
    $middleval = floor(($count-1)/2); // find the middle value, or the lowest middle value
    if($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
        $median = $arr[$middleval];
    } else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
        $low = $arr[$middleval];
        $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
        $median = (($low+$high)/2);
    }
    return $median;
}

function calculate_average($arr) {
    $count = count($arr); //total numbers in array
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $total = $total + $value; // total value of array numbers
    }
    $average = ($total/$count); // get average value
    return $average;
}

$home_values_array = array("100000", "120000", "150000", "157000", "180000", "198000", "220000", "1450000");

$median_home_value = calculate_median($home_values_array);
echo '<p>Median home value: $'.number_format($median_home_value).'<br />';
$average_home_value = calculate_average($home_values_array);
echo 'Average home value: $'.number_format($average_home_value).'</p>';
```

So my question is, How do I group specific sku so that I can loop out multiple arrays of the prices per sku like in the script above..

```
$home_values_array = array("100000", "120000", "150000", "157000", "180000", "198000", "220000", "1450000");
```

An example of the database fields:

```
SKU    PRICE
123    454.60
123    723.74
123    523.11
321    21.00
321    45.05
```

Comment: As the data is in a database is there any reason why you can't get this information from a SQL query? You seem to be going to an awful lot of effort to do something which is easy in SQL.

Comment: I can group by fine. but i can't seem to get it in to the array format needed for the functions.

Comment: why do not try with MySQL? no need to do all lines of code like: `SELECT sku, AVG(price) as average_price FROM 'table' GROUP BY sku`

Comment: Yes, This works but it doesn't give me a median as well. Which is why Im trying to figure out how to get the functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purely SQL approach:

```
SELECT m.sku, AVG(m.price) as median, MAX(a.price) AS average
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sku
        , price
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prices t2 WHERE t2.sku = t3.sku) AS ct
        , seq
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prices t2 WHERE t2.sku < t3.sku) as delta
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            sku
            , price
            , @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS seq
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY sku, price
        ) AS t1, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS x 
        ORDER BY 
            sku
            , seq
    ) AS t3 
    HAVING (ct%2 = 0 AND seq-delta BETWEEN FLOOR((ct+1)/2) AND FLOOR((ct+1)/2) +1)
        OR (ct%2 <> 0 AND seq-delta = (ct+1)/2)
) AS m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        p.sku
        ,AVG(p.price) AS price
    FROM
        prices AS p
    GROUP BY sku
) AS a
    ON a.sku = m.sku
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY sku;
```

Hat tip to this answer for the median calculation https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158333/median-with-group-by